# 10-min moving average to 1-hour moving average in R

Tags: r, moving-average

I have a set of weather data in 10-min moving average, showing in 1-min interval. I would like to transform it to 1-hour average.

```
               Date   Direction   Speed
1  2017-07-06 00:01:00        93   7.3
2  2017-07-06 00:02:00        92   7.4
3  2017-07-06 00:03:00        92   7.3
4  2017-07-06 00:04:00        91   7.4
5  2017-07-06 00:05:00        91   7.3
6  2017-07-06 00:06:00        91   7.3
7  2017-07-06 00:07:00        91   7.2
8  2017-07-06 00:08:00        90   7.1
9  2017-07-06 00:09:00        90   6.9
10 2017-07-06 00:10:00        91   6.7
...
(thousands of row of data in 1 min-interval
```

* Direction and Speed above are in 10-min moving average

For normal moving average built-in functions, they are encountering each and every neighborhood values, like:

```
rollmean(timeLine$Speed, 60, fill=FALSE, align = "right")
```

will result roll mean on every values encountering n, n-1, n-2, n-3, ... , n-59.

However, since my raw data is already the 10-min average, I just need to take values n, n-10, n-20, n-30, n-40, n-50 in order to transform it to a hourly mean.

For example, if I want a hourly data of 2001-07-06 10:00:00, I just need to take average on the followings:

- 2001-07-06 10:00:00
- 2001-07-06 09:50:00
- 2001-07-06 09:40:00
- 2001-07-06 09:30:00
- 2001-07-06 09:20:00
- 2001-07-06 09:10:00

Is there any possible way such that I could calculate it smoothly on R?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update 1: Here is the dput(head(timeLine, 10))**

```
structure(
  list(
    Date = structure(c(1499270460, 1499270520, 1499270580, 1499270640, 1499270700, 1499270760, 1499270820, 1499270880, 1499270940, 1499271000),
    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Hong_Kong"), 
  Direction = c(93L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 91L),
  Speed = c(7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 6.9, 6.7)),
  .Names = c("Date", "Direction", "Speed"),
  row.names = c(NA, 10L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should post output of `dput(timeLine)` , since it is a data.table object; at least it `print`s like one. Posting the `print` representation makes it kind of a PITA to get it parsed correctly. Even the wonderfully flexible `fread` function will give you 5 columns when you clearly have only three. The default print output of POSIXt columns unfortunately has spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The output of `dput(head(timeLine, 10))` is `structure(list(Date = structure(c(1499270460, 1499270520, 1499270580, 
1499270640, 1499270700, 1499270760, 1499270820, 1499270880, 1499270940, 
1499271000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Hong_Kong"), 
    Direction = c(93L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 
    91L), Speed = c(7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 6.9, 
    6.7)), .Names = c("Date", "Direction", "Speed"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rollapplyr` (`r` at the end means right align) in zoo allows specification of the offsets by using `width = list(offset_vector)` like this:

```
transform(timeLine, avg = rollapplyr(Speed, list(seq(-50, 0, 10)), mean, fill = NA))
```

Comment: Nest and simple! Is  `align="right"` became dummy in your statement? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `rollapplyr` with an `r` at the end uses `align="right"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there's almost certainly a more elegant way, but I think this works. I used the `lubridate` package to make it easy to convert to datetime format:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = read.csv(text="
              Date,Time,Direction,Speed
              2001-07-04,09:01:00,310,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:02:00,310,3.9
              2001-07-04,09:03:00,310,3.9
              2001-07-04,09:04:00,310,3.9
              2001-07-04,09:05:00,300,3.9
              2001-07-04,09:06:00,300,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:07:00,300,3.9
              2001-07-04,09:08:00,300,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:09:00,300,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:10:00,300,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:11:00,290,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:12:00,290,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:13:00,290,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:14:00,290,4.0
              2001-07-04,09:15:00,290,4.0", sep=",", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)

lagged_avg = function(col) {
  lag_positions = c(0,10,20,30,40,50)
  sum = 0
  for (n in lag_positions) {
    sum = sum + lag(col, n)
  }
  return(sum/6)
}

df = df %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(paste0(Date," ",Time))) %>%
  mutate(lag = lagged_avg(Speed)) %>%
  select(-Date, -Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [tibbletime package](https://github.com/business-science/tibbletime) - specifically, the `collapse_by()` function is helpful. The following should work (would be easier to test with a more data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)

tbl_time(timeLine, index = Date) %>%
  filter(minute(Date) %in% seq(0, 50, 10)) %>%
  collapse_by("hour", clean = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

Note: Depending on how you think about your hours, you may want to change the `collapse_by` line to `collapse_by("hour", clean = TRUE, side = "start")` - by default, it will use `side = "end"`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to first filter for `0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50th` minutes data. One can divide `minute` of date/time by `10` and check for `remainder` to be equal to 0 to filter data for `0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50th` minutes data. Apply `zoo::rollmean` for every 6 observations. In that way mean for each hour will be calculated using 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th, 50th and 0th minutes data.  Finally filter for `minute == 0` (for an hour).

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

timeLine_mod %>% filter(minute(Date) %% 10 == 0) %>%
mutate(meanSpeed = rollmean(Speed, 6, fill = FALSE, align = "right")) %>%
filter(minute(Date) == 0)

#                  Date Direction Speed meanSpeed
# 1 2017-07-06 01:00:00        91   6.7       6.7
# 2 2017-07-06 02:00:00        91   6.7       6.7
# 3 2017-07-06 03:00:00        91   6.7       6.7
```

**Data:** Since OP has provided data for only 10 minutes which is not sufficient to calculate hourly average. Hence, I have extended data to cover 3 hours:

```
timeLine <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1499270460, 1499270520, 1499270580, 
1499270640, 1499270700, 1499270760, 1499270820, 1499270880, 1499270940, 1499271000), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Hong_Kong"), 
Direction = c(93L, 92L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 91L), 
Speed = c(7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.4, 7.3, 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 6.9, 6.7)), 
.Names = c("Date", "Direction", "Speed"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
class = "data.frame")

#Extend data to cover 3 hours as
timeLine_mod <- timeLine %>% complete(Date = seq(min(Date),
         min(Date)+60*60*3-60,by="1 min"))

#Repeat the value of Direction and Speed
timeLine_mod$Direction <- timeLine$Direction
timeLine_mod$Speed <- timeLine$Speed
```

Comment: It will become an hourly average rolling with hour interval, but not 1 min interval

Comment: @TLee I think you had mentioned that data you got is already 10 min moving average showing every min. Perhaps that's what you have written in 1st line of question. But if you haven't then first calculate 10 min moving average and then  solution I have mentioned. May be you can do it in single pipe.